# How can I solve ClassCastExeption?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> **Can you tell me how to resolve this ClassCastExeption?**

*java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiPlainTextFileImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.model.NlModel.getFile(NlModel.java:230)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager$ModelChangeListener.modelActivated(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:454)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.model.NlModel.lambda$activate$0(NlModel.java:184)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.util.ListenerCollection$forEach$1.run(ListenerCollection.kt:80)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:398)
    at com.android.tools.idea.util.ListenerCollection.forEach(ListenerCollection.kt:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.model.NlModel.activate(NlModel.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.activate(DesignSurface.java:925)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.DesignerEditorPanel.activate(DesignerEditorPanel.java:190)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.DesignerEditor.selectNotify(DesignerEditor.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorTabbedContainer$2.selectionChanged(EditorTabbedContainer.java:151)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.fireSelectionChanged(JBTabsImpl.java:947)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.executeSelectionChange(JBTabsImpl.java:903)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.access$1900(JBTabsImpl.java:52)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl$9.run(JBTabsImpl.java:862)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorTabbedContainer.lambda$null$2(EditorTabbedContainer.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorTabbedContainer.lambda$new$3(EditorTabbedContainer.java:161)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl._setSelected(JBTabsImpl.java:858)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.select(JBTabsImpl.java:849)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.TabLabel$1.mousePressed(TabLabel.java:96)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6547)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4532)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:702)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

```
>MainActivity.java:
```

package com.example.findyourgift;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}*

> activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.242" />

</androidx.constraint
```